# Doppler shift and flux

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, observers, doppler-effect

I am trying to solve this problem: A body emits photons of frequency 
$\omega^*$ at equal rates in all direction in its rest frame. An observer is moving with speed V relative to the body in the x direction. Find the rate at which the photons are received per unit solid angle $dN/dt' d\Omega'$ a large distance away in the observer's frame as a function of angle $\alpha'$ from the x'-axis. I tried to use this $cos (\alpha') = \frac{cos (\alpha)+V}{1+Vcos (\alpha)}$ for the change in angle, the time is a factor of $\gamma$ and N is constant. However I am not sure how to transform the solid angle. Normally I have $d\Omega = sin(\theta)d\theta d\phi$, but I am not sure how to connect this to the above formula in a simple way, such that to get the solid angle in the S'. I assume I can work in the small angles approximations, as the source is far away, but I am still not sure how to do it. Any idea?

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.